# ModRewrite and php files

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

On server is this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /www_new
```

Because there are few other projects. I must now point everything to that folder. I have problems with swf, woff, svg and ttf files but I add them here and it's working right

```
RewriteRule !\.(swf|woff|svg|ttf|pdf|js|ico|gif|jpg|png|css|rar|zip|tar\.gz)$ index.php [L]
```

but my problem is that I can't use it for file uploadify.php

How can I point to it?

Maybe some rewrite rule too? Like if address is /something/uploadify.php then point me to /www_new/something/uploadify.php

Also, it would be best if that rule can be only for main server, not localhost.

Thank you for any suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following rule before your existing rules , :

```
RewriteEngine on
# this checks to see that the requested uri value is not starting with the "target folder" and prevents rewrite looping 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/www_new
# rewrite /anychar/uploadify.php to /www_new/anychar/uploadify.php 
RewriteRule ^(.*uploadify\.php)$ /www_new/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I improve it a little bit with this condition first (for main server, not localhost) 

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.myserver\.com